# SlowCheetah does not Process Transforms

Tags: slowcheetah

I copied a `web.config` that already has show cheetah transforms defined from one project to another.  The transforms show up in the new project just fine, and I can edit them.  However, they are not being applied when I run the project.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project itself must be configured to apply transforms.

To do that, in the new project:

- Right-click `web.config` (or whichever file has the transforms)
- Add Transform

This will setup the project to apply Slow Cheetah transforms, and will leave the copied / edited transforms in place.

This action may take a moment because the project is unloaded, modified, and re-loaded.